# Tips for finding patterns in an array

Tags: arrays, indexing, design-patterns, bit-manipulation

I have an array of 256 values. Those 256 values were calculated in some mysterious way, and range from 0-3 inclusive. To increase the efficiency of my program, I can calculate the results of the array given an index, rather than actually looking up in the array.

Basically, the program gives me an index, which would be looked up in the array, but I know that I can actually calculate what will be in that index using the index number itself.

For example

```
a[0] = 3, a[1] = 2, a[2] = 1, ... , a[254] = 1, a[255] = 1
```

I'm not actually asking for the calculation here, but looking at every number in the array, what are some tips on figuring out the pattern? I apologize if this is poorly worded, I'll attempt to clear up any questions.

Comment: Name of the array for example. Code that uses it. IQ (no offence, but many IQ tests give you a sequence of numbers, and you have to guess the next value).

Comment: You could also read this to understand the problem better: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There likely isn't a general approach to solving this problem without having some idea about the function that generated the data. You mentioned "efficiency" — if there really are only 256 values and the function to generate the data has any kind of computational complexity, it's probably more efficient to just keep it as an array.

Comment: Yep, in most cases you create an array for a speedup. Wast majority of algorithms are slower than a simple lookup.